# How to safely log request body from HttpServletRequest without interferring main logic?

Tags: java, jackson

In my Web service app I have the request object which is an instance of HttpServletRequest. The problem is some client(customer) is sending some invalid request in the body and I want to log it. In my logging class I have the reference to the request object, but using the function below I got a "StreamClosed" exception. I think it is because Jackson has already consumed the stream and closed it in its json deserialization process.

So my question is, how do I safely log the request body in case it is invalid? Apparently I cannot log it up-front before the Jackson tries to deserialize it because that would tamper the input stream.

```
        public static String getBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    String body = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    body = stringBuilder.toString();
    return body;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a filter that wraps the request in an object that allows the InputStream to be retrieved multiple times.

A simple Request wrapper implementation would do the following:

1. Read the original Request's InputStream into a byte[] then close it.
2. Create and return a new ByteArrayInputStream every time the getInputStream() method (of the wrapper) is called.

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend try to use a dedicated lib to log the requests, please take a look in:

https://github.com/zalando/logbook